How assign DOI to an existing dataset
We have collected a muti-pettabyte dataset during our experiment which is stored on external, but accessible from outside of our lab dataset. How I can register a DOI for my dataset and how I can reference it in my publications?

The easiest solution would be to upload your dataset to a repository that would take care of registering the DOI for you. If you work at a university or other public institution, check with your librarians or possibly with your IT department if they offer this kind of service, be it the hosting or just the DOI registration. Here is an example of a university library helping researchers to obtain DOIs: https://www.dundee.ac.uk/library/research/publishing/obtaining-digital-object-identifier-doi
If your organization does not offer this kind of service, given the size of your dataset, I'm not sure you'll find such a service for free (as an example there's this paid service: https://www.surf.nl/en/services/surf-data-repository, but definitely look if you find others).
If you want to register a DOI yourself and simultaneously want to host the dataset yourself, your dataset will have to be already accessible through a URL (it's unclear from your question if it's the case). Then, you'll have to go through to a DOI registration agency (RA).
Here is the list of current RAs: https://www.doi.org/the-community/existing-registration-agencies/ . The details depend on the RA, but don't expect the process to be trivial. Three things in particular:

RAs will generally expect you to register DOIs on a regular basis for other datasets or publications, so they may not accept your request if it's just a one-time thing.
Maintaining the system has a cost for the RAs, so they may expect you to pay a fee, possibly a recurring fee.
DOIs are supposed to be persistent, so your contract with the RA may impose you to make sure that the link to the dataset does not rot. If you breach the contract, consequences vary depending on the RA, so look carefully at your obligations in the contract.

Anyway, if you want to take the path of obtaining DOIs yourself, check the main DOI website as well as the registration agencies websites, you should find all the info you need.
